# Zooming to particular feature among selected features by feature id in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, features, zoom, qgis-2.6

Using QGIS 2.6 and PyQGIS, I want to zoom to features one by one on click among selected features list and change the colour on zoom without unselecting the other features.

```
canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.selectToFeaturesIds(layer,id)   # not supported in QGIS 2.6
```

or

```
canvas.panToFeatureIds(layer,id)     # not supported in QGIS 2.6
```

I have enlisted the selected features in Qtablewidget and want to zoom to them one by one by mouse click without unselecting others

Comment: Any reason why you keep QGIS 2.6? QGIS 2.18 is the oldest QGIS version which is maintained

Comment: ya, need to do with QGIS 2.6 only!

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented at QGIS 2.6?

Comment: selectToFeaturesIds and panToFeatureIds are not supported by QGIS 2.6 ., so it gives error